# Implement Google analytics in LWR community using lWC

Tags: experience-cloud, google-analytics, lwr

Is it possible to track events using Google Analytics inside LWC in a Community? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. The details to add this to your LWR site as well as sample code are available here:

[Use Google Analytics in LWR Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/advanced_use_google_analytics.htm)